# How to use wizard assemblies attached in VsixMainfest in project templates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wizard, vsix, project-template

I have a vsixmanifest file that has an assembly attribute. The file looks like:

```
<Content>
<ProjectTemplate>Solution</ProjectTemplate>
<Assembly AssemblyName="SolutionNameWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c39bfcc-223f-4c12-a5dc-55eeca7c61f7">
    Assemblies\SolutionNameWizard.dll
</Assembly>
```

I know that the assembly name and public key are correct.

Now, I am trying to use this assembly in one of my templates. Right now I have:

```
<WizardExtension>
      <Assembly>SolutionNameWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c39bfcc-223f-4c12-a5dc-55eeca7c61f7</Assembly>
      <FullClassName>SolutionNameWizard.IWizardImplementation</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

Is there something that I am missing? When I run the vsix I get the following error:

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'test.Web' Error: this template
attemtped to load component assembly 'SolutionNameWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c39bfcc-223f-4c12-a5dc-55eeca7c61f7'.
```

I know that templates require the assembly to be in the GAC, is that also the case when I am using vsix? I was hoping to avoid the GAC and still use my wizard.

**EDIT:** I changed the public key to the proper string as suggested in the answers, but am still having the issue.

**Edit 2:** in addition to the helpful answer below, here is a blog that I wrote after I finished this process. It links to a bunch of articles that I found to be very helpful: https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/2013/10/visual-studio-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else happens to stumble upon this question, I ended up following this guide: http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/09/14/build-a-multi-project-visual-studio-template/

It made the process (mostly) very easy. If anyone happens to run into similar issues, feel free to contact me and I can try to share what I learned.

**Edit:** here is short blog article I wrote after completing this process. It might be helpful for someone who stumbles upon this: http://www.thebhwgroup.com/blog/2013/10/visual-studio-templates/

Answer (score 3):

If your assembly is being provided via your VSIX, it does not need to be in the GAC.

Your PublicKeyToken is definitely *not* correct. You're using a Guid when it should be a 16-character hex string (8 bytes). See the following example:

MyAssembly, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**b03f5f7f11d50a3a**

You can find the PublicKeyToken value for your assembly by running `sn.exe -T MyAssembly.dll` from a VS command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for pointing out that issue. I corrected the publickeytoken in both locations, but am still having the same issue. Do you happen to see anything else that might be incorrect?